# Is it possible to sort the string from the list more cleverly?

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm doing algorithmic tasks - anagrams. The question is, how do I have a string list and I want to sort them alphabetically (in the sense I do not want to have a sorted list, only the list in which the elements are sorted by strings). Is it possible to do it cleverer?

```java
List<String> words = Arrays.asList("text1", "text2", "text3");

words = words.stream().map(s -> {
    char[] w = s.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(w);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char ch: w) {
        sb.append(ch);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @marspace: that will sort the string collection, not the characters in the string.

Comment: Yeah at first I couldn't make out what the OP was even saying.  Code makes sense though.  (I can't think of a "better" way to do this either, at least not an obvious one.)

Comment: @pbloz, no, there's no other way. At least without reflection. For this task you'd better use `StringBuilder` which has straight access to characters themselves, or simply an array of chars.

Comment: @pbloz, that's quite not what I meant. This code might work even worse due to `StringBuilder` resizing. What I meant is using `List<StringBuilder>` or `List<char[]>`, so that you do not waste time copying an array from `String` and can work directly on characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed if you're finding anagrams, streams are helpful for the whole task:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import static java.util.Arrays.stream;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Anagram {
  static List<List<String>> findAnagrams(List<String> dict) {
    return dict.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(w -> stream(w.toLowerCase().split("")).sorted().collect(joining())))
        .values().stream().filter(words -> words.size() > 1).collect(toList());
  }

  static List<String> getWords(String fileName) throws IOException {
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
      return lines.collect(toList());
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     findAnagrams(getWords("words.txt")).stream().forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}
```

On my old Macbook this prints 38,504 anagram sets found in a 5MB word list in 2 seconds. The biggest set has 15 elements:

```
[anestri, antsier, asterin, eranist, nastier, ratines, resiant, restain, 
 retains, retinas, retsina, stainer, starnie, stearin, Tersina]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this. I `split` the string into characters and create a stream, `sort the stream`, `join` each stream of characters into a string and then collect the strings into a `List`.

```java
  List<String> sorted1 = words.stream().map(
        str -> Arrays.stream(str.split("")).sorted().collect(
              Collectors.joining())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here is another way working with the character array.  I am not certain which one is best.

```java
  List<String> sorted2 =
            words.stream().map(str -> str.chars().sorted().mapToObj(
                  c -> String.valueOf((char) c)).collect(
                        Collectors.joining())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```